# XCode 環境での Jenkins 実行時のエラー

Tags: xcode, iphone, jenkins

Mac でJenkinsを利用したbuild環境を作成しようとしていますが、以下のエラーから進めなくなっております・・・。

エラーを元にいろいろと調べたのですがなかなか情報が見つからずこちらに記載させていただきました。
このエラーの原因がわかる方がいらっしゃったらアドバイスいただけないでしょうか？
お願いします。

```
Codesigning '/Users/jen/Documents/flappy.mobileprovision' with 'iPhone Developer: jen (######)'

/usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Developer: jen (######) --resource-rules=/var/folders/lm/------/T/oJurBLuvPy/Payload/flappy.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/lm/------/T/oJurBLuvPy/Payload/flappy.app Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)! Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10! /var/folders/lm/--------/T/oJurBLuvPy/Payload/flappy.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources ]

error: /usr/bin/codesign --force --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,resource-rules --sign iPhone Developer: jen (#######) --resource-rules=/var/folders/lm/--------/T/oJurBLuvPy/Payload/flappy.app/ResourceRules.plist /var/folders/lm/--------/T/oJurBLuvPy/Payload/flappy.app failed with error 1. Output: Warning: usage of --preserve-metadata with option "resource-rules" (deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10)! Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10! /var/folders/lm/--------/T/oJurBLuvPy/Payload/flappy.app/ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources
Failed to build /Users/jen/.jenkins/jobs/flappy/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/flappy-1-2014.12.27.ipa Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XCode6.1 のアップデートでいろいろ動かなくなった所の一つのようで、「`"ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources" error."`」はよく知られた問題のようです。

解決方法は、 XCode plugin の　ビルド設定で `Custom xcodebuild arguments`に

```
CODE_SIGN_RESOURCE_RULES_PATH="$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plist"
```

を追加することです。

参考 : [How do we manually fix “ResourceRules.plist: cannot read resources” error after xcode 6.1 upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516442/how-do-we-manually-fix-resourcerules-plist-cannot-read-resources-error-after)

Comment: Yamamoto様
回答いただき、本当にありがとうございました！おかげさまで無事解決し、buildさせることができました。
回答いただけなかったら解決までたどり着けなかったと思います。ご丁寧に回答いただき、本当にありがとうございました。